# Assign rights to remote folder using WMI

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python script that creates a folder on a remote server using WMI. Unfortunately i cannot find how to assign rights to this folder with WMI. Any alternatives?

I'm creating a folder with this script:

```
import wmi
conn = wmi.WMI('10.0.30.12', user='###', password='###')
conn.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine='cmd.exe /c mkdir E:/temp')
```